# Geometric proof in Calculus

Tags: calculus, geometry

In the following diagram:[image: similar triangles]

How does one conclude that the longer leg of the blackened triangle has length $Ld\theta$? I get the rest of the diagram and the similar triangles, but I do not see how the length of that leg is $Ld\theta$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This formula is just an approximation!

Comment: To me, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)#Length_of_an_arc_of_a_circle) is sufficient. In the limit, that leg *somewhat coincides* with a curved arc of a circle.

Comment: For the purpose of finding derivatives of trigonometric functions, I find [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_trigonometric_functions) very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at it in this way. An intuitive understanding of infinitesimal is when a segment of a curve is short enough, it can be replaced by a line segment. That is
$$\lim_{arc~length\rightarrow 0}arc~segment = line~segment$$
Thus, the length of that shadowed line segment is equal to the length of the arc segment from the circle that centered at the leftmost point and have radius $L$ and angle $d\theta$. That length is precisely $Ld\theta$ by arc length formula.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of differentials, the equation $\tan (\theta)=d\theta$ is in fact exact, not approximate. (By "differentials", I mean à la Leibniz, or in more rigor, as differential forms.)

Differentiating the tangent:
$$
d\tan\theta = \frac{d\tan\theta}{d\theta}d\theta = \frac{d\theta}{\cos^2\theta}.
$$

Now since:
$$
d\tan\theta=\tan(\theta + d\theta) - \tan\theta,
$$

we get:
$$
\tan(\theta + d\theta) = \tan\theta + \frac{d\theta}{\cos^2\theta}.
$$

For $\theta=0$, this is:
$$
\tan(0 + d\theta) = \tan(0) + \frac{d\theta}{\cos^2(0)} = 0 + \frac{d\theta}{1} = d\theta.
$$

So: $\tan(d\theta) = d\theta$.

EDIT: let me clarify. The first equation simply means that:
$$
\frac{d\tan\theta}{d\theta} = \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}.
$$

The second equation simply says that:
$$
\frac{d\tan\theta}{d\theta} = \lim_{\Delta\theta\to 0}\frac{\tan(\theta + \Delta\theta)-\tan(\theta)}{\Delta\theta}.
$$

Intuitively (and *only* intuitively), you can view $d\theta$ as a "small" $\Delta \theta$.

So, in terms of limits, writing $d\tan\theta = d\theta$ means:
$$
\lim_{\Delta\theta\to 0} \frac{\tan(\Delta\theta)}{\Delta\theta} = 1.
$$

Comment: Could you write a few comments about the first two equations? I am not familiar with differential forms and maybe these are common equalities.

Comment: I edited the answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, but equation 1 really takes away the whole idea of the proof...

Comment: What I mean is that the whole idea of the problem is to find the expression for the derivative of $\tan$

Comment: Oh, that's the problem? Then no, you can't use the formula above.

Comment: Yes, in the picture you see $T=\tan(\theta)$ and conclude thate $\frac{dt}{d\theta}T = 1 + T^2$

Comment: I mean, the formula is right, but you have to find it first. The picture is very clear for that, but only if you accept that $\tan d\theta \approx d\theta$. To accept this fact, you can't use the formula, because that's what you are trying to prove in the first place!
My approach is not wrong, but it's not what you have to use in this case.

Comment: The identity $d\tan\theta=\tan(\theta+d\theta)-\tan(\theta)$ is not correct, in fact you may easily check that $$\tan(a+b)-\tan a=\frac{1+\tan^2a}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}\tan (b)$$

Comment: It is a definition...

Answer (score 0):

That length equals $L\tan d\theta\approx Ld\theta$ for small $d\theta$.

Comment: Is there really nothing more exact than this? I actually remember finding how accurate the approximation of $sin\theta = \theta$ is using taylor's theorem...

Comment: $\tan \theta = \theta + \frac{\theta^3}{3} + \ldots$.

Comment: In the limit, it's no longer an approximation, but equal.

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure if I forgot but how did you even get the length to be $L \tan d\theta$?

Comment: $\tan d\theta$ equals the ratio of the length of the opposite side to the length of the adjacent side (=$L$).